# New task/New Event is not available in Activity related list in lightning

Tags: lightning-experience

New task/New Event is not available in Activity related list in lightning, I have checked all the permissions, still same problem, Is creating Global actions only way out?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If this is a custom layout you have to add them manually. Refer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activitytimeline_configure_call_task_event_tabs.htm&type=5) for more details, if still not visible refer this [troubleshoot guide](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316620&type=1&mode=1)